I need to find the state of the system at a general time, knowing the Hamiltonian and the state at $t=0$


The Hamiltonian for a certain three-level system is represented by the matrix
$$H = \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 & b \\ 0 & c & 0 \\ b & 0 & a\end{pmatrix},$$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real constants.

(a) If the initial state of the system is
$$| \psi(t=0)\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},$$
what will be the state of the system at the instant $t$, $|\psi(t)\rangle$?

My teacher said that we need to diagonalize the Hamiltonian in order to find how the system evolves. But is it really necessary? I assume that the relation $\langle E \rangle=[0,1,0]H[0,1,0]^T$ should work here. And therefore the $\psi(t)=[0,1,0]^T*e^{-\frac{i}{h}Et}$
Why wouldn't this work?

Please don't use screenshots/images. Instead, type the relevant passage using MathJax.

The relation you posted only works if the state is an eigenstate of $H$ with eigenvalue $E$. Is it?

Recall that Physics SE is a website in English. Please refrain from posting text in other languages. I translated the text from Portuguese to English and typed it out for you this time.

For this particular initial state, you do not need to diagonalize the Hamiltonian. The reason is that this particular initial state is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, and as a consequence you can just do the trick you wanted to do. If $|E(0)\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian with eigenvalue $E$, then the evolved state $|E(t)\rangle$ is given by
$$|E(t)\rangle = e^{- \frac{i E t}{\hbar}} |E(0)\rangle.$$
However, this only holds for eigenstates. Suppose you have a generic initial state
$$|\phi(0)\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \\ \phi_3\end{pmatrix}.$$
In this case, that expression does not work. More specifically, in general we have
$$|\phi(t)\rangle \neq e^{- \frac{i \langle H \rangle t}{\hbar}} |\phi(0)\rangle,$$
where
$$\langle H \rangle = \langle \phi(0) | H | \phi(0) \rangle.$$
Instead, what you have to do is write $|\phi(0)\rangle$ as a superposition of energy eigenstates and then evolve each of them individually. This is why your teacher said you need to diagonalize the Hamiltonian. The energy eigenstates have simple time evolutions, and we use these time evolutions to solve for the general case. More specifically, suppose $| E_j \rangle$ are the energy eigenstates with eigenenergies $E_j$. Suppose that
$$|\phi(0)\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^3 c_j | E_j \rangle.$$
Then the generic rule is that
$$|\phi(t)\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^3 c_j e^{- \frac{i E_j t}{\hbar}} | E_j \rangle,$$
which just uses the preceding formulae.
It is correct that, in general (for a time-independent Hamiltonian),
$$|\phi(t)\rangle = e^{- \frac{i H t}{\hbar}} | \phi(0) \rangle,$$
but $H$ in this expression is an operator and you need to consider the exponential of an operator (which is a well-defined object). Typically, the easiest way to compute this matrix exponential is to diagonalize the operator anyway.




The Hamiltonian for a certain three-level system is represented by the matrix
$$H = \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 & b \\ 0 & c & 0 \\ b & 0 & a\end{pmatrix},$$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real constants.


(a) If the initial state of the system is
$$| \psi(t=0)\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},$$
what will be the state of the system at the instant $t$, $|\psi(t)\rangle$?
My teacher said that we need to diagonalize the Hamiltonian in order to find how the system evolves.

For an arbitrary initial state, you would be obliged to perform the process of diagonalizing the Hamiltonian as part of figuring out how such an arbitrary state evolves in time. As part of the diagonalization process you will have to obtain the eigenvectors, not just the eigenvalues.

But is it really necessary?

By luck, it does not happen to be necessary for the specific initial state of Problem 3.a that you provided. It might be necessary for other parts of the problem.

I assume that the relation $\langle E \rangle=[0,1,0]H[0,1,0]^T$ should work here.

This relationship regarding the expectation value of the energy is not what your teacher asked you to find, and this expression would not tell you anything interesting about time evolution of the particular state of Problem 3.a.

And therefore the $\psi(t)=[0,1,0]^T*e^{-\frac{i}{h}Et}$

Lose the "and therefore." The above equation doesn't follow directly from the expression you wrote for the expectation value.
Regarding the state you propose, you happen to be correct, supposing that you can figure out the value to plug in for $E$.

Why wouldn't this work?

It will work for the particular state of Problem 3.a, assuming you can figure out the correct value of $E$ to use.
